# add any font to an HTML page

Tags: html, fonts

Newbie question: Can I embed any font into HTML. For example the Rockwell font?

Thanks!

Comment: A) You wouldn't *embed* it into HTML, rather you would probably *link* to it from your *CSS*, where it would be used to render text in your HTML. B) While you may be technically able to do this (as demonstrated below), the biggest issue is that you're not legally permitted to do so unless you have a license allowing you to 1) convert the font into another (more web friendly) format and 2) distribute that font. Services like Typekit are key in doing this in a way that is technically and legally sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Where FontFamilyName is what ever you want to call it and src: url('/font/font.otf'); is a link to the fonts file (much like using a background image).

```
@font-face {
    font-family: FontFamilyName;
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url('/font/font.otf');
}
```

You can then use the font like any other font family. ex:

```
p
{
font-family: FontFamilyName;
}
```

Comment: While the technique is correct, it lacks the explanation that would make this a good answer.

Comment: Browser support may vary. The following link may be helpful: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/how-to-achieve-cross-browser-font-face-support/

Comment: On the upside, this is the proper way to use a custom font on a web page.  On the downside, not all browsers support `@font-face`; a notable example is the Mobile Safari browser in the iPhone and iPad, which will simply ignore the `@font-face` section and treat the font as missing, following standard CSS font-replacement rules.

Comment: Also beware: you may not be legally allowed to post that for for web use.

Comment: look at my answer, it has links to all your need for true crossbrowser implementations :)

Answer (score 1):

Google offers a pretty nice service called [Webfonts](http://code.google.com/webfonts), check it out!

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the [bulletproof font-face syntax](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) you can embed most any font into webpages.

You can use a [free font-conversion service like font squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) to convert your font's into the formats you need to support all browsers :)

Comment: "[You] can embed most any font into webpages." — While that may be true *technically*, it is not so *legally*.

Comment: Good thing the question was "Can I embed any font into HTML" and not "Am I allowed legally to embed any font into HTML" then ;)

Answer (score 0):

take a look at **[`@font-face`](http://www.css3.info/preview/web-fonts-with-font-face/)** that allows you to use any font on your page - if the user does not have that font installed, it can be downloaded from a server and used to render the web page.

An example

```
@font-face {
    font-family: DeliciousRoman;
    src: url(http://www.font-face.com/fonts/delicious/Delicious-Roman.otf);
    font-weight:400;
}
```

Take a look at **[font-face](http://www.font-face.com)** website for more details. Be aware that there are some cross browser issues with @font-face - for this, I would recommend looking at the **[stellar work of Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/)** in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using @font-face in your stylesheet, but you have to remember that IE doesn't always handle these properly. Use this code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: (the name you want to call it by);
    src: url('path/to/font.eof');
}
```

You can also use .otf, or .ttf.

Answer (score -1):

Not really. You are limited to [cross-browser](http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html) fonts if you want to be sure the page will display the same across browsers.

That being said, there is an interesting service called [Typekit](http://typekit.com/) that lets you embed fonts using JS and CSS3. It only works for modern browsers.

Comment: You really aren't limited to cross-browser fonts as most of the answers point out.

Comment: Notice the word SURE. To be absolutely sure, you are limited to cross-browser fonts. There are services like TypeKit and Google Webfonts, but they do not guarantee compatibility. Depending on outside fonts can have some loading issues like font flashing as well.

Comment: @KyleWpppd Actually, people fail to realize that Linux GUI don't usually have a lot of "web safe" fonts like Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, etc.

Comment: @coreyward Acknowledged. How are you handling the Linux users? My personal experience with Ubuntu has been that typography is God-awful. Before your comment I never even considered accommodating for Linux.

Comment: I don't really consider visuals for anybody using Windows, IE, or Linux. I figure you're used to unpolished visuals if you're using any of them. That said, Typekit provides browser samples for Ubuntu, and they look decent. IMNSHO, Ubuntu renders type better than Windows.

Comment: If we're going the TypeKit route, then we are depending on JS, no? 

I agree that MS type rendering is poor, but I believed that was due to font antialiasing turned off by default. My personal issue with Ubuntu is not the rendering, but that the fonts themselves did not seem as appealing as the defaults on OS X or Windows.